# Java application servers monitoring and profiling concepts

Tags: java, jboss, weblogic, application-server, server-monitoring

I want to write monitoring and profiling tool for java application servers such as JBoss , Weblogic, etc. But I don't know monitoring and profiling concepts well. Is there any referenced resources for these concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server#Java_application_servers) [with](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling) [the](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Performance_Management) [basics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0304_polozoff/polozoff.html) [of](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080/best-traffic-performance-usage-monitoring-module) [concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404986/simple-server-monitoring-with-java) [and](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs81/portblty/jvmtools.html) [look](http://www.jboss.org/jbossprofiler) [at](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) [existing](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Java-Applications-and-Servers) [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130067/best-server-performance-monitoring-tool-for-java-servers)